# Parsing 3 integers to hex and returning as RGB hex

Tags: c#

I've been doing this Kata and I'm a little stuck on finishing this function. I've searched for parsing but haven't found variants that parse shorthand hex's into RGB. So far I have

```
public static string Rgb(int r, int g, int b)
{
    r = Math.Clamp(r, 0, 255);
    g = Math.Clamp(g, 0, 255);
    b = Math.Clamp(b, 0, 255);

    string hexR = Convert.ToString(r, 16);
    string hexG = Convert.ToString(g, 16);
    string hexB = Convert.ToString(b, 16);

    string res = "000000";
    res = res.ReplaceAt(0, hexR.Length, hexR);
    res = res.ReplaceAt(2, hexG.Length , hexG);
    res = res.ReplaceAt(4, hexB.Length , hexB);
    return res.ToUpper();
}
```

It works but single digit hex's arent parsed correctly for example with an input of `212,53,12`
the result is `D435C0` where as it needs to be `D4350C`

Would greatly appreciate advice and feedback to the function as I'm trying to improve.

Comment: Any reasons why you didn't use stringFormat ? I see no reason here to convert data, why not just use  return $"{r.ToString("x2")}{g.ToString("x2")}{b.ToString("x2")}", instead of converting and replacing a string values

Comment: I didn't know ToString directly converted it to the appropriate value, shortened and fixed the function with that though thank you. Is there somewhere I can read more about that "$" though because I keep seeing it yet I haven't encountered it in my studies yet

Comment: *Is there somewhere I can read more about that "$"*: Sure, `$` is a shorthand operator for `String.Format`

Comment: Do you need the `#` on the front if so you could use `ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b))`

Comment: No the # wasn't necessary. Thanks @JeremyThompson, I feel pretty dumb but I just kept getting weird results while searching for "what does $ do in c#"

Comment: @Armin Don't bother currently with the "$", it is not important in current context, it is just more simple way to insert arguments into a string creation process. What I suggested can be written like return r.ToString("x2") + g.ToString("x2")+b.ToString("x2"); Please keep in mind that the string is immutable in c# =)

Comment: If you want to read about the `$`, lookup _interpolated strings_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
public static string Rgb(int r, int g, int b)
{
    r = Math.Clamp(r, 0, 255);
    g = Math.Clamp(g, 0, 255);
    b = Math.Clamp(b, 0, 255);

    int res = r * 256 * 256 + g * 256 + b;

    return res.ToString("X");
}
```

Comment: I did this in the end but thank you! string res = String.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", r, g, b);
  return res.ToUpper();

Comment: You don't need the cost of duplicating the string with a ToUpper call. If you use `X2` you'll get upper case. Using `x2` gives you lower case

Answer (score 1):

You can use a format string, [as mentioned by @Demon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7109905/demon) in the comments

```
return $"{r:X2}{g:X2}{b:X2}";
```

Note that `X2` gives it in uppercase, whereas `x2` will give lowercase